# send response from node.js to Jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

Iam new to node.js
I want to get data fetch from db and send that returned value to Jquery.
 in the following code

```
exports.signin = function (signupCollection, context) {
var record = utils.httpBody(context.req);
signupCollection.find({ },{email: record.email,password: record.password},function(err, result) {
      console.log("result-------"+result) // prints the data correctly
      if(!err) return result;
    });    
}
```

`result` prints the correct data i want...it is getting properly

In jquery

```
var data = {   
    "email": $('#email').val(),
    "password": $('#password').val()   
   };
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/signIn",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("sign in succesfully!!"); // here i want to  getthe result data
                console.log("SIGN IN RESPOSEE----"+data);             

            }
        });
```

inside this i couldn’t get the  resultant data returned from node,js

```
success: function (data) {
alert("data-------------"+data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have written the result to `http.ServerResponse` (`response` object) and call `response.end()`.

Are you using any web framework? My guess is `context.res` would be the `response` object.

Use:

```
return context.res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
```

instead of

```
return result;
```

Reference:

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Comment: yessss...context.res is a response object.how can i modify the code like you said?

Comment: am getting http.js:593
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');

Comment: `result` seems to be an `Object`, used `JSON.stringify()`.